# Visual studio C++ IntelliSense issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, intellisense, call-hierarchy

I seem to be having two issues with my project after I converted from VS 2005 to VS 2010.

> IntelliSense: command-line error: invalid macro definition:
>   _WIN32_WINNT>=0x0501

And I also cant seem to be able to do a "Call Hierarchy" on any of the methods or properties.

I would appreciate if someone can help me with these. Thanks

Comment: The Intellisense "compiler" is awfully buggy.  I don't trust it at all.  Rely on the real compiler to give you compilation warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to ignore the intellisense warnings. The call hierarchy wasn't working because I was in the release mode. Should be in debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same issue - the same error message, the same non-functioning call hierarchy and badly-working Intellisense.

The problem was with the preprocessor flags in the project, the following were defined:

`WIN32;_DEBUG;WINVER=0x501;_WIN32_WINNT 0x0501`

Notice the lack of `=` after `_WIN32_WINNT`. Adding the `=` fixed all the issues.

P.S., this is a Console application that doesn't use any of the Windows header files, which is why the lack of the _WIN32_WINNT macro did not cause a more severe problem.